# Expectation of product of two non-independent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have random variables simultaneous PDF $p(x,y)=\frac{6}{5}(x+y^2)$ on $0<x<1,0<y<1$. I am to show that $W=XY$ has a mean.

I have found marginal PDF $g(x)=\frac{2}{5}+\frac{6}{5}x$ on $0<x<1$ and $h(y)=\frac{6}{5}y^2+\frac{3}{5}$ on $0<y<1$.

These are not independent since $p(x,y)\neq g(x)h(y)$ and thus I can't use that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$. I am stuck on this one here. How else would I show that there exists a mean for $W=XY$?

Comment: $W=XY$ is non-negative and bounded (it is never less than $0$ or more than $1$), so it has a mean

Answer (score 4):

$$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^1 xy \cdot \frac{6}{5}(x+y^2) \, dy \, dx.$$